# Explain Java Interfacing?

Tags: java

Can someone explain what or how interfacing works (in Java), never really understood it.

Comment: Interfacing???? wats that? did u mean Java Interfaces!?

Comment: Do you mean an interface, by chance?

Comment: If you are asking about the use of interfaces in Java, that question has been answered many times on this site already.

Comment: If you tried already and did not understand, maybe you need a different approach to learning, e.g. have someone explain it on a whiteboard.

Comment: Never really understood this question!

Answer (score 0):

An Interface describes methods and their signature without having an implementation.
All classes which implement an interface can be replaced by each other.

See also [Interface concepts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_%28computer_science%29)

Example:

The interface [java.util.List](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is specialization of Collection and is implemented by 
    `AbstractList, ArrayList, LinkedList, Vector` this means all methods declared in this interface can be called on an instance of objects of this type.

EDIT: Less abstract

```
interface PlaySound {
    public void play();
}

public class MP3Player implements PlaySound {
    public void play() {
       // do complicated stuff
    }
}

public class WAVPlayer implements PlaySound {
    public void play() {
       // do complicated stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It makes your class more formal about the behavior. As interface in every thing,in java it shows a way to communicate with your class. If you mean the mechanic - I think it is not so important to understand it. Concept is main thing here.

Answer (score 0):

To get the point across about interfaces, I recommend you read [Head First Java](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596004651), especially the inheritance chapter in the book. Infact, everything in the book is spot on for any java beginner to understand.